# AngularJS error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, undefined

Im working on a project that involves AngularJS and I am running into an error cant seem to figure out. Needless to say, I am a newbie on this hopefully you guys could help me figure this out cause I 've spent quite sometime on this issue.

here is my code

WatchboxCtrl.js
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c68fbd87574d61377b54981a09f66e5

and this is where the error occurs

FleetMapCtrl.js

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9df7bc7c54a09c91dd60cd009ba9ff91

Ultimately, what i want to do is, having the app shows multiple alerts and if i click on one of the alert, the app should automatically zoom in onto the unit that the alert is originated. Previously, I have the "id" as string and it was working fine;however, I later on changed the "id" to integer and the zoom functionality no longer working. The console in gives me this error every time i click on the alert :

`angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at flyTo (FleetMapCtrl.js:320)
    at Object.fn (FleetMapCtrl.js:287)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14308)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21571)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)`

It showing the error at line 320 in fleetmapCtrl.js but I cant figure out/understand why it's not working.

Please help. I searched everywhere in order to fix it but I cant seem to get it resolved. Im desperate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for `undefined` in your little method.

```
function isUndefinedOrNull(val) {
    if (val === "" || val === null || val === "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You are checking for the string `"undefined"` not `undefined`.

```
console.log(undefined==="undefined");  //false
```

So it should be without the quotes

```
function isUndefinedOrNull(val) {
    return val === "" || val === null || val === undefined;
}
```

Now why is it undefined? You would need to track down where flyTo is being called and figure out why the watch is not returning the new value.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the newval is no more a string and there is no zoomlevel in newVal.
When you are accessing newVal.zoomLevel it will give undefined only.
I think the below line is having issue. I coudn't see anywhere you are assigning zoomLevel to that object. Please excuse me if i missed out the same.
$scope.markers = getMarkers($scope.mapData[newVal.zoomLevel.toString()]);